# Not showing Runtime Permissions Dialog in a particular Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, runtime-permissions

Runtime Permissions Dialog is not showing in a particular Fragment. For example there are 5 Fragments. In One Fragment there is a Map. When user clicks on the particular Fragment a the dialog should popup to the user.

So far what i have done is:-

```
if (Prefs.getLatitude(getActivity()).equalsIgnoreCase("") && Prefs.getLongitude(getActivity()).equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                mCheckPermissionP();
            }
```

The mCheckPermissionP() contains the following code:-

```
public void mCheckPermissionP() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);

        }
    }
```

Inside onRequestPermissionresult() the codes are as follows:-

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults.length == 0 || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    initilizeMap();
                } else {
                    initilizeMap();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Nothing is getting called.

Comment: check if permission is already granted

Comment: No Popup is showing...

Comment: did u check in settings that permission is already granted (if already granted it wont show Popup)

Comment: Checked.... Deny...

Comment: debug code and see it reached the statement or see any error log in present

Answer (score 1):

**I Faced the same issue but it was my fault**.
I forgeted to define permissions in the **Manifest**
Allow permission dialog didnt appear if permission is missing in the Manifest try defining these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

In The Manifest